# Run time vs design time

Tags: runtime, design-time

I read somewhere that somebody could access a config value during run time but not during design time. Whats the difference between run time and design time in this context?

Comment: Kind of like the difference between tea-time and lunch-time.

Comment: I read somewhere that somebody could access a config value during run time but not during design time. I had no clue what he ment to say

Comment: So edit your question to explain the context of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Design time is when somebody signs off our word documents and our UML diagrams with a cheery "That looks fine!"  Run time is when we execute our code and it fails with a horrible crash and burn.

The advantage of a technique like [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is that it compresses the gap between design time and run time to the point where they are the same thing.  This means we get instant feedback on how our design actually works when translated into code, which should result in a better design and fewer embarrassments when our code goes live.  YMMV.

Comment: I wonder if, applying enough TDD or similar techniques, the gap closes so much that you get to nap time directly. Something like the old 'you end up with a one-line program that does not work'.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza - With TDD we start out with "a one-line program that does not work" and move towards something more substantial which actually does work.

Comment: I know, I know. But your phrasing is actually opposite to that, and I felt jestful.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza - I have re-read my post in the light of your comments and I see what you mean.  I have re-edited it somewhat.   Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3):

Design time is when you are creating a design based on the requirements, or creating some UML diagrams.

Run time is when you are implementing your design and running the code.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about .NET applications? In that case design time probably means something more specific - when your GUI is presented within the Visual Studio designer. This gives you a working view of your application, but it is running in a [design time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164159.aspx) environment. Many .NET controls have a [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property that allows you tell whether the control is running in design time view or not.

Answer (score 2):

design time is when you design some code

run time is when you execute the code you designed

Answer (score 1):

Run time is when your program runs. Design time is when your program is designed.

Answer (score 1):

Design time refers to processes that take place during development, Runtime refers to processes that take place while the application is running.

For instance, constants that are hardcoded in your application are set at design time, such as...

```
// you need to recompile your solution to change this,
// hence it is said that its value is set at design time.

const string value = "this is set at design time";
```

Whereas configuration values that are pulled from a config file would be said to be set at runtime. Such as...

```
// You do not need to recompile your solution to change this,
// hence the value is said to be set at runtime. 

string value = ConfigurationManager.GetValue("section", "key");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you must aim for the ideal equilibrium between design time (let's take it to mean *'the time you spend designing and developing the app'*, though it's a bit incorrect) and run time, which I take to mean *'the time the user stands looking at the hourglass waiting for his important report to be rendered'*.

Too much focus on 'design time' and you might run out of the scheduled programming time, and your client will pull out of the contract, he'll badmouth you, and kittens will die. Too little, and your program will, as they say, suck. Remember that *'shipping is a feature, one your program should have'*.

Unless what they meant by "run time" is "runtime" and that means something else entirely.